# sql eliminate duplicate rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to eliminate duplicate rows in access table. And I want to follow these lines userid grouping, sorting each line in accordance with timestamp。My table looks like this:

```
userid    pagetag     time
 111       1-2      19:08:02
 111       1-2      19:08:02
 111       1-2      19:00:11
 111       1-2      19:00:12
 113       1-3      13:02:04
 113       1-3      13:02:04
 113       1-2      13:04:08
 115       1-2      14:18:56
 115       1-2      14:14:22
 115       1-2      14:14:22
```

And the result looks like this:

```
  userid    pagetag     time
  111       1-2      19:00:11
  111       1-2      19:00:12
 *111       1-2      19:08:02*
 *113       1-3      13:02:04*
  113       1-2      13:04:08
 *115       1-2      14:14:22*
  115       1-2      14:18:56
```

Comment: Are you actually wanting to `delete` the records?  If so, that's a different question then your previous.  You cannot order results in your table, sql is unordered in nature.  You can however `delete` duplicate data.  If you just want to `select` the non-duplicates, then `distinct` and `order by` are still the same answers...

Comment: Yes,I want to delete the duplicate rows . But the result is not displaying 
chronologically

Comment: You can delete the duplicates -- easy enough.  You cannot reorder results stored in a table though.  Databases store data unordered -- regardless of what they may look like when you view the table, the order is not guaranteed.  Just supply an `order by` clause when viewing the data, whether thats a form, query or report.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and fastest method would be a simple group by:

```
Select
    userid,
    pagetag,
    [time]
From
    LogTable
Group By
    userid,
    pagetag,
    [time]
```

This will both eliminate the dupes and provide the sorting.

Then use this query as your source for the further processing.

Answer (score 0):

This query achieve the results you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid, pagetag, [time]
FROM LogTable
ORDER BY userid, [time]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is Sql syntax to remove duplicate rows

```
With DulicateRowsCTE as
(
  select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by  userid,pagetag order by  userid ) as rowno   from [Table_1]

)
   select * from DulicateRowsCTE where rowno>1
```

Comment: The question is for **MS Access**, so a `PARTITION BY` approach is not valid, and even on another RDBMS it would not answer the question